# Semantically, can I put <hr> inside <nav> element in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I need to make fullscreen overlay navigation that includes: pages(vertical navigation links), hr, and social media icons. For me, it is easier to have all of these things inside nav tag to style them.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Our works</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sure, why not? It's totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you can use a hr element inside the nav element (it is semantically fine) - you would be better to use styling to create the line below the links - such as a border-bottom on the ul.

```css
nav ul {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 0
}

nav ul li { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Our works</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class = "social-icons">
  <span> social icons go here </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.